# Executing javascript code after non-jquery ajax call updates part of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page I want to show/hide a field based on a value selected from a drop down field. This works fine when page loads. But when an ajax call updates part of the page, of course my jquery document.ready does not fire. I tried many solutions about this issue but no luck. I can not edit that ajax call to add a call back, I have no access to that.

Here is my simple Jquery code: (The legacy product has jquery1.3 but I can upgrade this version)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //my code to hide/show a field
    $('#mySelect').change(function(){
         //show or hide
    });
});
```

This works when the page loads, but when the following ajax call executes, my jquery doesn't work any more: (Note: I can not edit this code)

```
function sendCommand(a,c,e,f,g,j,l,m){
    if(AJAX._engineReady&&(a=document.getElementById(a))){
        var o=a.selectedIndex;
        if(!(o<0)){
            a=a.options[o].value;
            c=upsertURLParam(c,"OCTYPE",a);
            o=document.getElementById(m);
            m=null;if(o)m=o.value;
            o=document.getElementById(j);
            storeUserValues(o);
            o=new AJAXRequest;
            o.setCtxtParams(c);
            o.setTimeout(6E4);
            /*
            * lots of parameter setting omitted here
            */
            AJAX.send(o);
            AJAX._engineReady=!1
        }
    }
}
```

I tried different methods such as jquery .on(), .live(), .delegate(), etc I have not found a way to fix. Also, the jquery .ajaxComplete() seems to be used only when we are making jquery-ajax calls which is not the case here. Any help would appreciated.

Comment: try  $('#mySelect').trigger("change") when you AJAX call return

Comment: Thank you. **When AJAX call return** you mean? I can not edit that ajax call, It is a closed product.

Comment: Don't you have any success callback? How do you know when the request is executed successfully or when there's an error? You have to call the `.trigger("change")` manually. But you have to know when the request finishes

Comment: Thanks. I did not write that ajax to care about onSuccess/onError, and looking at the above function in chrome dev tools, it is exactly like what I posted here in that "sendCommand" method except some parameters i omitted, they don't check if it succeeded or failed. It is called by the onchange() on a select input. What I see after it runs, some fields are removed.